# SQL Server Update with check of duplicates

Tags: sql-server, duplicate-data

In SQL Server 2008 I have a table `tblProfile` with employee numbers (`EmID`) and profileID (`ProID`). `EmID+ProID` are a combined primary key.

I found "duplicates" on the `EmID`, which come from the employee table. Each employee can have multiple `ProID`, but the combination of both ID's is unique.

Of course, from the side of the `EmID` they are no duplicates, but in the employee table they are duplicates.

For example in `tblEmployee` there are:

```
EmId        Lastname      Firstname   Birthdate  
------------------------------------------------
22          Mayer          Frank      1960-01-01  
23          Meyer          Frank      1960-01-01
```

Now I want to "`clean`" the table with this logic. To clean the `tblEmployee` is not the problem but how to clean the `tblProfile` with this logic?

Let's assume I want to delete `EmID = 23`, because I want to keep the older record. If there is an existing profile for `EmID = 23` which has not been defined for 22 it is not a problem, but if there already is a combination of 22 + 2, I would create an error when changing 23 + 2 to 22 + 2.

Data:

```
EmID    ProID  
22       2  
23       2  
23       1
```

In that case I would have to delete 23 + 2 but change 23 + 1 to 22 + 1.

The result should be

```
22       1
22       2
```

which is my goal.

I really do not know how to handle that.

I cannot start with

```
delete from tblprofile 
where EmID = @duplicateEmID
```

as I delete the record which I might use to keep the profile....

Thanks your help

Michael

Comment: it would be simpler and better just to delete the `22` record... the problem starts when you have multiple profiles for both duplicated records.

Comment: As Long as I could rely on that every employee has all his ProID I could do this, but the Problem is, that the user forgot to define 22 + 1 but when creating employee 23 (the same as 22 of course) he defined him correct. So I do not want to loose any Definition for a specific employee.
I think the solution is somehow to select both and find the "Maximum" of both and then correct or delete the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You will do this in multiple, simple steps.

1)  Run a query to identify the Employee dupes that you want to delete (not the oldest).   Store them in a temp table.  Also add a column called "NewID" in the temp table.

2)  Run a query to update the temp table and set the value of NewID to the oldest emId for that employee.

3)  Run a query to insert the combination of NewID plus ProfileID into the Profile table WHERE the ProfileID currently exists with the old employee id, AND the combination of NewID & ProfileID does not already exist.

4)  Delete all the rows from Profile table that have the old profileIDs in them.

Breaking down a complex issue into it's most basic steps often makes it easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks your steps.
But how should query at 3) look like?

Comment: Start with Temp table, LEFT JOIN to Profile table on empId, and use WHERE NOT EXISTS to check for the combination you want to insert.